# Practical Page-Replacement Algorithms

Tags: reference-request, operating-systems, memory-management, paging

Could anyone suggest other page replacement algorithms that are applicable to the real world aside from

- FIFO,
- Second Chance (Clock),
- Enhanced Second Chance and
- Random?

Answer (score 4):

The [Least-Recently Used (LRU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Least_recently_used) is a very common algorithm for page replacement, especially in system softwares that are exposed to data access of [temporal locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Spatial_and_temporal_locality_usage).